# Set a list of acceped zones in Eureka

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Is their a way to ignore zone or define list of accepted zone in Eureka, for example if we have 3 zones ( `office`, `shahbour`, `joe` )

I want the services in zone `shahbour` to only use services defined in `shahbour` primary and `office` as secondary and ignore all other zones in this example `joe`.

I tried it as below and it is working to prefer same zone but if their is no service on same zone it do load balance on all the others zones

```
spring:
  profiles: shahbour
eureka:
  instance:
    metadataMap:
      zone: shahbour
  client:
    region: lebanon
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://office:8761/eureka/
    preferSameZoneEureka: true
    availabilityZones:
      lebanon: shahbour,office
```

I thought setting availabilityZones set this but it is not .

*This is for development environment where i am trying to setup each developer to use his machine as a zone and if service does not exist use office server as backup but don't use other developers .*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any place to set the accepted list of zones in eureka but what i found is that we can create our custom `ServerListFilter` in `Ribbon` that is used in both `Feign` and `Zuul` so below is the code

```
public class DevServerListFilter extends ZonePreferenceServerListFilter {

    private final List<String> acceptedZone = new ArrayList<>();

    public DevServerListFilter(String[] acceptedZones) {
        for (String zone: acceptedZones) {
            this.acceptedZone.add(zone);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initWithNiwsConfig(IClientConfig niwsClientConfig) {
        super.initWithNiwsConfig(niwsClientConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Server> getFilteredListOfServers(List<Server> servers) {
        List<Server> zoneAffinityFiltered = super.getFilteredListOfServers(servers);
        Set<Server> candidates = Sets.newHashSet(zoneAffinityFiltered);
        Iterator serverIterator = candidates.iterator();
        while (serverIterator.hasNext()) {
            Server server = (Server)serverIterator.next();
            if(!acceptedZone.contains(server.getZone())) {
                zoneAffinityFiltered.remove(server);
            }

        }
        return zoneAffinityFiltered;
    }


}
```

*The above filter extends `ZonePreferenceServerListFilter` with a check on list of accepted zones , any server not in this list is ignored .*

```
@Configuration
@RibbonClients(defaultConfiguration = MyDefaultRibbonConfiguration.class)
public class MyRibbonConfiguration {
}
```

*Default configuration for all my clients*

```
@Configuration
public class MyDefaultRibbonConfiguration {

//    @Bean
//    public IPing ribbonPing(IClientConfig config) {
//        return new PingUrl();
//    }

    @Bean
    public ServerListFilter<Server> ribbonServerListFilter(IClientConfig config,EurekaClientConfigBean eurekaClientConfigBean) {
        String[] availabilityZones = eurekaClientConfigBean.getAvailabilityZones(eurekaClientConfigBean.getRegion());

        DevServerListFilter filter = new DevServerListFilter(availabilityZones);
        filter.initWithNiwsConfig(config);
        return filter;
    }

}
```

*The Configuration Code , note that this has to be in an excluded path from @ComponentScan as request in [documents](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.3.1.RELEASE/) , and i used the availability zone property but any list can be used.*

[github sample](https://github.com/shahbour/microservices-security)